# Build the Linux kernel without gcc optimization

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, gcc, optimization, kgdb

I follow one of many tutorials found on Google results to build and debug the Linux kernel with gcc and kgdb/gdb. And I end up by discovering that is all waste of time. Since I can't compile the kernel without gcc optimization -O0 neither -Og. There's no config option for removing optimization. And last but not leat, Linus said years ago that is against debugging.

Saying that kgdb must exist for some reason. I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of variables/arguments "**optimized out**" and let the debugger step through the code sequentially and not jumping from everywhere to everywhere?

Comment: Would you mind linking to the tutorial you’re following? I understand you probably want an answer that’s not focused on a specific tutorial, but it would help give the background.

Comment: I am not a fanatic, you could suggest to me any other working tutorial, no matter the tools used. Here is the kind of tutorials I found https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html

Comment: Ah, good, that’s part of the kernel documentation so it should be trustworthy ;-). Other interesting documents include https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/kgdb.html and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html; but there’s no guide to disabling optimisation as far as I’m aware.

Answer (score -1):

The Linux kernel source tree has Makefiles (many of them actually) which contain all the flags you're looking for, including `-O2` which you can remove or replace with `-O0`.

Here's how you can change the compilation flags for all of them (which might be risky according to Stephen Kitt):

```bsh
cd linux
find . -name Makefile -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/-O2/-O0/g'
or
find . -name Makefile -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/-O2/-Og/g'
```

Or change them only for the root Makefile (which is safer):

```bsh
cd linux
sed -i 's/-O2/-O0/g' Makefile
or 
xargs -0 sed -i 's/-O2/-Og/g' Makefile
```

`man gcc` says `-Og` is good for debugging purposes.

Comment: Do you know if the kernel will build and run with a global `-O0`? I know individual components can be built like that, and flags can be set using `CFLAGS_file.o` in individual Makefiles, but it used to be the case that at least parts of the kernel needed `-O1` or more. I haven’t checked recently, so I don’t know what the situation is nowadays...

Comment: You're right, I've discovered `-O2` in various `Makefile`s for other components. Looks like `sed` must be run recursively.

Comment: My point is that there is a decent chance those flags in sub-`Makefile`s are there for a reason, and blindly changing them is liable to break the build in unobvious ways, for example not inlining `setjmp`s which need to be.

Comment: Well, the OP will learn it the hard way.

Comment: What a lovely attitude...

Comment: @StephenKitt I've left both options - for all Makefiles or just for the root one.